# Using PHP curl, how to pull results of FB search?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am attempting to access the results of a search on Facebook via PHP curl so I can write information about the search results into a database and check for incremental changes. The code is below, and I can get it to work similarly by pulling my pages name and count of likes,

```
<?php

function get_fb_data($get) {
define("TARGET", "https://www.facebook.com/search/".$get."/likers");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, TARGET);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
return $exec;
curl_close($ch);
}

$fb = get_fb_data('506764276135128');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($fb);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

The Facebook search does rely on being logged in to function, so I might have to pass user credentials along with an app key to access the results. However, I am hoping not as it has become extremely difficult and confusing to navigate through the App Developer section of the site and get approval for an app.

What I would like to pull off the page is the number of results, and the name/profile id for each result.

Comment: Are those search results available publicly in Facebook (i.e. without friending those individuals)? I recommend not posting personal data if it is meant to be private.

Comment: yeah, the graph search searches public profiles too, although i would remove the screenshot too because of privacy.

Comment: Thanks, was just trying to illustrate what the target page would look like.

Comment: Edit history burninated by a mod/dev! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would actually be scraping and is not allowed on Facebook. Use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1) instead (see the section about "Searching").

It does not offer the same functionality as the Graph Search that is integrated in Facebook, but it is the only permitted way and you can search for Pages, Users, Events, etc).